# Get records from two relations (one is pass through accessor) with paginate

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7, laravel-relations

**Laravel 7.x**

I need to get posts from two `relations`. Look:

> User has Posts;

> User has Friends (accessor);

> Friends has Posts;

**How can I get all own (User) posts and all posts by each Friend, and paginated?**

Which the best way to do that?

*Only to pass the idea that I want to say:*

```
$user = User::find(1);
$posts = $user->with('posts','friends.posts')->paginate(15); // I wanna get only the Posts collection
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest query your `Post` model and then apply filter for user and related friends filter.

```
$user = User::with('friends')->find(1);
$userIds = $user->friends->pluck('id')->toArray();
array_push($userIds, $user->id);
$posts = Post::whereIn('user_id', $userIds)->paginate(15);
```

Comment: That's the way I was going to do it. But I would very much like to use the relationships of the eloquent. Anyway, that works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[hasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)**, this relationship is a bit complicated to understand a provide shortcut way to access data of another mode relation. 
In your **User** model make relationship like this way :

```
public function posts()
{
   return $this->hasManyThrough(
     Post::class,
     Friend::class,
     'user_id', // Foreign key on friends table...
     'friend_id', // Foreign key on posts table...
     'id', // Local key on users table...
     'id' // Local key on friends table...
   );
}
```

Now you can get all `posts` from `User` model like this way :

```
$user = User::find(1);
$posts = $user->with('posts')->paginate(15);
```

Comment: So... look my scenario: I have a User model, This represents a user. The relationship with another user is made with accessor (getFriendsAttribute). $user->friends returns my confirmed friends. The friends also are User. The User model has a posts method that returns all posts from that user. I think that accessor is the problem.